# Datatype for latitude & longitude in mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql

I want to use google maps in my project and for that i need to store lat/lng values in database .So what will be the datatype for lat/lng in MySQL? should it be decimal or spatial (geometry,geometryColllection or point or any other)?

PS: lat will be separate field and lng will be separate field.

Please help me find the solution.

Thanks in  Advance.

Comment: I agree that the manual's discussion of geometry data types is woefully inadequate. Nevertheless, I suspect that this is widely discussed. That said, if lat and long are separate columns then DECIMAL(11,7) will suffice.

Comment: Note that PHPMyAdmin is simply an IDE. Its use has no bearing on the structure of the underlying database.

Comment: ok i will use decimal for it  however what will be datatype if not separate like lat/lng in same column?

Comment: I would suggest using a POINT and then using the ST_Longitude() and ST_Latitude() functions. This allows you to use the other built in functions such as the ability to plot distances between points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECIMAL(10,8) for latitude
DECIMAL(11,8) for longitude